# virtual terminals in ubuntu server do not recognize newly installed nvm

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, terminal

Ubuntu server (as all linuxes) has the ability to multitask using ctrl-F1 up to ctrl-F7. Each of these key combos puts you in another terminal. While in the main terminal (ctrl-F1) I installed nvm (node version manager) and also node.js. These work fine in the ctrl-F1 terminal. But when I go to another terminal, ubuntu thinks they are not installed.  ECHO $PATH gives the same result in all virtual terminals. Default programs like nano, vim, etc can be started in all the different terminals. How can I 'fix' this issue so that I can run learnyounode in one terminal, nano in another terminal, and node in another terminal?

Comment: i dont know what you meant by 'source'.  i did 'source .profile' but that did nothing. i rebooted and that seems to work. thanks for the pointer but i couldnt give you credit because you only commented.

Comment: Heh, I thought it was too obvious... You got the idea, but the changes were probably in `.bashrc`, not `.profile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have shells running on those terminals which were initiated before you ran the installer, they will not have received the updated configuration. Log out and then back in, or figure out which configuration file(s) to `source` anew. Probably

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

but there could be pertinent changes in `.bash_profile` and/or `.profile` as well (and system config files, if you did a system-wide install).